# C# How to get tweet from link

Tags: c#, twitter

As said in topic, How can I receive Image, Author and Content of the Tweet by the link?
Example Link : https://twitter.com/HonorioAranda/status/284190886341005312
How can I get datas from this link?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Read [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter has published an API.

Take a look at it:

> http://api.twitter.com/

I'm sure you find something useful there. 
E.g. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/show/:id

Just adapt it or use it.
It returns a string.